# Use Tensorflow Embedding Projector in Flask App (host the projector on a webpage)

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is a continuation of [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014236/how-to-use-the-embedding-projector-in-tensorflow-2-0) post. Other related issues are [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2471#issuecomment-580423961) about tensorboards in general.

### Question

My question is: how do you embed a tensorflow embedding visualization created with https://projector.tensorflow.org/ in a FlaskApp, or on a webpage?

### Attempted solution using "Publish" option

The most straight forward way I can guess is **publishing my embedding visualization** and then linking to it, but the [provided tutorial link](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/embedding_viz) is throwing an error for me. I have a website where I am trying to **host my projector config JSON file**, but I keep getting a "Cross-Origin" fetch request error.

#### Projector config JSON file

```
{
  "embeddings": [
    {
      "tensorName": "Petrarch's tensor",
      "tensorShape": [
        1000,
        50
      ],
      "tensorPath": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yi-ye-zhi-qiu/5b7f107e5b926a6b02bb900753aaa4a7/raw/87b359b496fceda1afb0e4ebfa320388f98a57f9/tensors.tsv",
      "metadataPath": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yi-ye-zhi-qiu/69a200a737690e6032513541fa1311e8/raw/fd23d45cfb08d6c28ac0c794b56e9a548e4bcf80/metadata.tsv"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Current attempt @ hosting projector JSON file

My webpage file that I am trying to host off of looks like this:

http://34.212.100.77/petrarchtensor

Does anyone have any advice on how to host a projector config JSON file properly?

If there are simpler approaches to hosting an embedding visualization on my webpage, I would really appreciate that as well.

Please let me know if I can help clarify my question in any way.

Thanks!

Comment: This [Add tensorboard embedding visualization in my own web application](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2078) may help you. Thanks!

Comment: I'll check this out, thank you